# UITextView, user scrolls uitextview but then it snaps back to original position, whats wrong?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I currently have a `UITextView` which is contained in a `UIViewController` using the following code:

```
UIViewController *container = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
container.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 1000);
//[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height

container.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
container.view.clipsToBounds = YES;

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
imgView.frame = container.view.frame;

imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[container.view addSubview:imgView];
[imgView release];

UITextView *textContained = [[UITextView alloc] 
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, container.view.bounds.size.width, 1000)];
//container.view.bounds.size.height

textContained.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:14];
textContained.scrollEnabled = YES;
textContained.editable = NO;

textContained.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textContained.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textContained.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

textContained.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
textContained.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
textContained.contentSize = CGSizeMake(container.view.frame.size.width,
container.view.frame.size.height);
```

I then set my `UItextView` text property with some text, which extends past the current screen size. I then add my `UITextView` to my container using the following code.

```
 switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        textContained.text = @"LOTS AND LOTS OF TEXT";

        [container.view addSubview:textContained];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:container animated:YES];
        [textContained release];

        break; 
    default:
        break;
 }
 [container release];
```

When I test this code, the text appears just fine in the `UITextView` and everything looks ok. But the problem is when I try to scroll down to see the remainder of the text. Everytime I scroll down the `UITextView` scrolls back in to its original position. I have tried several ways to get this to work, but I think I need some fresh eyes to see what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to delete textContained.contentSize = ... and see? everything else  looks fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't want to set the contentSize of a UITextView, since it is determined by the length of text automatically.

Try to make the height of textView smaller. For example:

```
UITextView *textContained = [[UITextView alloc] 
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, container.view.bounds.size.width, 50)];
```

And give it more text, like:

```
textContained.text = @"LOTS AND LOTS OF TEXT\nLOTS AND LOTS OF TEXT\nLOTS AND LOTS OF TEXT\n\nLOTS AND LOTS OF TEXT\nLOTS AND LOTS OF TEXT\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, your suggestion led me to find that I was not subtracting the size of the tab bar I had in place. Thank you very much. It was driving me crazy...needed some fresh eyes.